# Razor Collection binding malfunction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I face a weird issue with an ASP.NET Core 3.1 website.

I use Razor generated webpages, and I bind a collection of objects from a ViewModel class. It works like a charm, until  I delete one of this object from this collection. I can see that the object is correctly deleted into the controller, that the updated collection is sent to the Razor Engine, and that the Razor Engine inserts the updated collection into the webpage.

But, in the end, the browser is receiving an incorrect collection, containing the deleted item and missing the last item from the collection, **despite this is not what the controller sent**. *Something* is modifying this collection after the webpage generation and I cannot figure out what, I am getting completely crazy.

The cache of the browser is disabled (and I double checked that the HTML received matches the HTML displayed), I don't have any custom made middleware running after the Razor Engine, I don't have any client side script nor AJAX, and the controller only run once upon request.

Would you have any hint on further troubleshooting steps? How can I dive into ASP Engine to figure out where is this HTML modified?

Detailled steps :

- `FooView` is initialized with 4 items, Id from 1 to 4, Names `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3`, `Foo4`
- Client clicks on `Foo2` Delete button
- `FooController` processes the requests, and updates the collection which now contains Id = {1,3,4}, Names={`Foo1`, `Foo3`, `Foo4`}
- `FooController` sends this collection to the Razor Engine, an by inserting a breakpoint, I can assess that Foo1, Foo3 and Foo4 are inserted, but no Foo2
- When it comes back to the browser, I get `Foo1`, `Foo2` and `Foo3` in the table. `Foo4` is missing.

```
public class FooVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class MasterViewModel
{
    public string OtherProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty2 { get; set; }

    private List<FooVM> Foos { get; set; }

}

public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("Delete")]
    public IActionResult DeletePOST(MasterViewModel model, string deleteId) {
        if (int.TryParse(deleteId, out int id) && model.Foos.Any(x => x.Id == id)) {
                model.Foos.Remove(model.Foos.First(x => x.Id == id));
            }
            return View("FooView", model);
    }
}
```

```
<!-- language: html -->

//FooView.cshtml File Extract
@model MasterViewModel
<form asp-controller="FooController " asp-action="UpdatePOST" method="post" id="detailedform">
<table>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Foos.Count; i++) {

            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                <input asp-for="@Model.Foos[i].Id"  readonly/>
            </td>

            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                <input asp-for="@Model.Foos[i].Name" />
            </td>

            <td nowrap="nowrap" class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" asp-action="DeletePOST" name="deleteId" value="@Model.Foos[i].Id" style="background-color:transparent; border:none">
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" style="color:red"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            </tr>
        }

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, I figured out that when the Razor page is generated, **there was a discrepancy between the data in the Model object and ViewData.ModelState dictionary** that I cannot explain. The Model object was containing the updated list, whereas the ModelState embedded dictionary was containing old key/value pairs, refering to the submitted list (not updated one).

When doing a debug inspection, the cshtml file @Model.Foos[i].Name variable shows the correct value, but it seems like the value computed later on, used for generating the final HTML, is taken from the ModelState which was not matching.

Is this a bug?

Anyway, I solved the issue by adding a ModelState.Clear() into the Controller before generating the view.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("Delete")]
    public IActionResult DeletePOST(MasterViewModel model, string deleteId) {
        if (int.TryParse(deleteId, out int id) && model.Foos.Any(x => x.Id == id)) {
                model.Foos.Remove(model.Foos.First(x => x.Id == id));
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View("FooView", model);
    }
}
```